Why does accessing the DB via JPA causes the app to quit?
For a long time, sometimes my app would just shut down for no apparent reason (on Ubuntu linux).
I added many debug statements, and I think I just nailed the particular line:
The log says:

15-12-2024 22:47:52.168 Positions thread INFO
c.a.controller.PositionsController:[124] - Trying to find symbol WDC
15-12-2024 22:47:57.358 Positions thread TRACE
c.a.dal.mysql.MyEmptyInterceptor:[68] - Thread Positions thread called
the SQL: SELECT * FROM
Auto_Investments_Linode_LIVE.position_each_record WHERE id in ( SELECT
id - 1 as id FROM Auto_Investments_Linode_LIVE.position_each_record
WHERE symbol = ? ORDER BY id desc ) LIMIT 1;
15-12-2024 22:48:00.742 Positions thread TRACE
c.a.dal.mysql.MyEmptyInterceptor:[69] - Threads accessing the DB: {}

And thats it! As you can see in the code below, it should end in:

Got record from DB

How can a simple DB access cause the app to quit (it happend dozens of times)?
How can I fix it?
And this is the code:
PositionsController
log.info("Trying to find symbol {}", curr.getSymbol());
PositionsRecordEntity latestPositionsRecordEntity = positionRecordRepository.getLatestRecordOfSymbol(curr.getSymbol());
log.info("Got record from DB");

MyEmptyInterceptor
@Override
public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
    log.trace("Thread {} called the SQL: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(), sql);
    log.trace("Threads accessing the DB: {}", threadsAndOpenConnections);
    return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
}

PositionsRecordRepository
@Query(value = "SELECT * " +
        "FROM Auto_Investments_Linode_LIVE.position_each_record " +
        "WHERE id in (" +
        "   SELECT id - 1 as id" +
        "   FROM Auto_Investments_Linode_LIVE.position_each_record " +
        "   WHERE symbol = :symbol " +
        "   ORDER BY id desc " +
        ") " +
        "LIMIT 1;", nativeQuery = true)
PositionsRecordEntity getLatestRecordOfSymbol(String symbol);

The entire method in PostionsController:
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String list(@RequestParam(name = "soa", required = false) Boolean showOnlyAvailable,
                       @RequestParam(name = "download", required = false) Boolean download) throws Exception {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("Positions thread");
        if (download != null && download) {
            log.info("Do not download - delete");
            mappedByteBufferHandler.delete(fileName, TYPE_OF_FILE);
        } else if (!location.equals("local") && mappedByteBufferHandler.exists(fileName, TYPE_OF_FILE)) {
            return mappedByteBufferHandler.read(fileName, String.class, TYPE_OF_FILE).toString().replace("\\n", "");
        } else {
            log.info("File exists? {}", mappedByteBufferHandler.exists(fileName, TYPE_OF_FILE));
        }

        System.gc();
        log.info("Positions called");

        /*if (tableOfPositions.findByFetchDate(LocalDate.now()) != null && !location.equals("local")) {
            log.info("Fetching from DB");
            return tableOfPositions.findByFetchDate(LocalDate.now()).getTableStr();
        }*/

        StringBuilder theTable = new StringBuilder(CONSTANT_VISIBLE_HEADERS + "\t\t<table class=\"sortable\">");
        PositionsTable positionsTable = new PositionsTable();
        theTable.append(positionsTable.getColumns());

        Set<OutputOrderEntity> allOrders = dailyPurchaseLogCache.fetchAllOrders(false);
        List<PositionsRecordEntity> positionEntities = positionsFetchService.fetch();

        ZoneId easternTime = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now(easternTime);
        Boolean inTradeSessionNow = (currentTime.isAfter(LocalTime.of(9, 30))) && (currentTime.isBefore(LocalTime.of(16, 30)));
        int indexOfYesterdayInArr = inTradeSessionNow ? 1 : 0;
        Float dividendSum = 0f;
        
        Map<String, Float> dividendsOfSymbol = alpacaActivities.totalDividendsBySymbol(ActivityENUM.DIV);

        for (int i = 0; i < positionEntities.size(); i++) {
            memoryLogger.logMemory();
            log.info("dividendsOfSymbol size: {}", dividendsOfSymbol.size());
            log.info("dividendsOfSymbol example: {}", dividendsOfSymbol.entrySet().iterator().next());
            log.info("i = {}", i);
            PositionsRecordEntity curr = positionEntities.get(i);
            // NEEDS FIXING!!!
            log.info("Trying to find symbol {}", curr.getSymbol());
            PositionsRecordEntity latestPositionsRecordEntity = positionRecordRepository.getLatestRecordOfSymbol(curr.getSymbol());
            log.info("Got record from DB");

            if (curr.getAvg_entry_price() != null && curr.getCurrent_price() != null) {
                try {
                    String symbol = curr.getSymbol();

                    if (!Arrays.asList(badSymbols).contains(symbol)) {
                        List<Values> valuesFromPurchaseDate = new ArrayList<>();
                        if (shouldContinue(symbol, allOrders, valuesFromPurchaseDate)) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        long daysEndIsBiggerTheOpen = valuesFromPurchaseDate.stream().filter(d -> d.getOpen() > d.getClose()).count();
                        if (showOnlyAvailable && Float.parseFloat(curr.getQty_available()) > 0f) {
                            log.info("Appending to table");
                            // REVIEW BEFORE USE!
                            theTable.append(new TableData(false, alpacaLink.replace("{*}", curr.getSymbol()),
                                    i + 1, createdAt, curr.getSymbol(), curr.getAvg_entry_price(), curr.getCurrent_price(), curr.getQty_available(), curr.getCost_basis(), curr.getMarket_value(),
                                    Float.parseFloat(curr.getMarket_value()) - Float.parseFloat(curr.getCost_basis()), curr.getChange_today(), curr.getLastday_price(), curr.getQty(), curr.getUnrealized_pl(),
                                    dividendsOfSymbol.getOrDefault(symbol, -1f)).
                                    createString(Float.parseFloat(curr.getCurrent_price()) > Float.parseFloat(curr.getAvg_entry_price())));
                            break;
                        } else if (!showOnlyAvailable) {
                            log.trace("Symbol not exists");
                            Float yesterdayDiff = valuesFromPurchaseDate.get(indexOfYesterdayInArr).getClose() - valuesFromPurchaseDate.get(indexOfYesterdayInArr).getOpen();

                            Integer color = Float.parseFloat(curr.getCurrent_price()) > Float.parseFloat(curr.getAvg_entry_price()) ? null : 1;
                            if (color == null) {
                                if (!inTradeSessionNow) {
                                    color = yesterdayDiff >= 0 ? null : 2;
                                } else {
                                    color = Float.parseFloat(curr.getChange_today()) >= 0 ? null : 2;
                                }
                            }

                            log.info("Creating vars");
                            float percent = Float.parseFloat(curr.getMarket_value()) / Float.parseFloat(curr.getCost_basis()) * 100 - 100;
                            float numberOfMonthFromStart = Duration.between(createdAt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(), LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay()).toDays() / 30;
                            String totalPercent = printNumber(percent) + "%";
                            String percentThisYear = printNumber((percent * 12 / numberOfMonthFromStart + 1)) + "%";
                            String yesterdayDiffStr = printNumber(yesterdayDiff) + " (" + printNumber(valuesFromPurchaseDate.get(indexOfYesterdayInArr).getClose() / valuesFromPurchaseDate.get(indexOfYesterdayInArr).getOpen() * 100 - 100) + ")%";
                            Float dividends = dividendsOfSymbol.getOrDefault(symbol, -1f);
                            Float dividendPercentage = -1f;
                            Float dividendsPerMonth = dividends == -1 ? -1 : dividends / numberOfMonthFromStart;
                            String createdAtStr = createdAt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
                            dividendSum += dividends;
                            
                            if (dividends != -1f) {
                                dividendPercentage = dividends / Float.parseFloat(curr.getCost_basis()) * 100;
                            }
                            theTable.append(positionsTable.addRow(color, false, alpacaLink.replace("{*}", symbol),
                                    i + 1, createdAtStr, curr.getSymbol(), curr.getAvg_entry_price(), curr.getCurrent_price(),
                                    totalPercent, percentThisYear, curr.getCost_basis(), curr.getMarket_value(),
                                    yesterdayDiffStr, printNumber(Float.parseFloat(curr.getChange_today())),
                                    curr.getLastday_price(), curr.getQty(), curr.getUnrealized_pl(), dividends, dividendPercentage, dividendsPerMonth,
                                    (((float) daysEndIsBiggerTheOpen / (float) valuesFromPurchaseDate.size())) + "(" +
                                            daysEndIsBiggerTheOpen + "/" + valuesFromPurchaseDate.size() + ")"));
                            log.info("Appending to table");
                        } else {
                            log.trace("else");
                        }
                    } else {
                        log.info("Symbol {} doesn't exists!", symbol);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e.toString(), e);
                }
            }
        }

        log.info("Final append");
        ZoneId localTimezone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Jerusalem");
        LocalDateTime localTime = LocalDateTime.now(localTimezone);

        theTable.append("\t\t\t<script src=\"https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js\"></script>");
        theTable.append("\n\t\t</table>\n");
        theTable.append("\n\t\t</br>Dividend sum: ").append(dividendSum);
        theTable.append("\n\t\t</br>Datetime of production: ").append(localTime.toString().replace("T", " ")
                .substring(0, localTime.toString().indexOf(".") - 1));
        theTable.append(BODY_HTML_END);
        log.info("Fetched all positions");

        //tableOfPositions.save(new TableOfPositionsEntity(theTable.toString()));

        String htmlPositionsTable = theTable.toString().replace("*TITLE*", "Positions");
        mappedByteBufferHandler.write(fileName, trimBackspaces(htmlPositionsTable), TYPE_OF_FILE);

        System.gc();
        // the server doesnt suuport this somehow :(

        return trimBackspaces(htmlPositionsTable);
    }


Don't post screenshots of code, use text with proper code tags. The screenshot isn't readable.

Please post the full method. Containing the log statements. You now just printed 3 lines, what does the full method look like?

Its a long method. Why do you need it? I can show you what you need.

Without knowing the whole method from the PositionsController it is impossible to know what I need or not.

If you have no log in java for shutdown, it should be your OS (ubuntu) that OOM Kill you app, you can check in your syslog

It does say "kernel: Out of memory: Killed process". However, I print logs of the memory taken, and its not nearly that big!
This is a log statement 26 seconds before the crash:
15-12-2024 22:47:34.018 Positions thread INFO  com.alpaca.utils.MemoryLogger:[39] - Allocated memory: 1172.0MB, Used memory: 400.33038MB, Free Memory: 1647.6696MB
